# Passing parameter to dynamically created handlers

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Here is my problem. I have a function where I dynamically create `<input />` elements and I am trying to register a handler on `mouseclick` with parameter. I call this function few times and only the last input has the handler assigned. Here is the simplified code:

```
function create() {
    var div = document.getElementById("myId");
    var vRemove = document.createElement("span");
    vRemove.innerHTML = "remove";
    var foo = 4;
    vRemove.onclick = function(){ remove(foo); }
    div.innerHTML += " ";
    div.appendChild(vRemove);
}

function remove(id) {
    alert(id);    
}

create();
create();
create();
```

and in HTML I have only one div:

```
<div id='myId'></div>
```

When I click the 3rd element an alert pops up but those other two do nothing at all. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is.  When you run this code in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Cy8Bk/), it seems to respond to a click in all three spans.  Please clarify what the problem is.

Comment: Oh it was working u are right. I left 1 line of code becouse I thought it's not important: div.innerHTML += " "; (see edited post). It was just testing code with no css and I needed space between created spans. Wonder why this couse this problem. I dont know how does appendChild work internally, but adding some text into a div and later appending child seems doable for me.

Comment: OK, I've added an answer that describes why the `div.innerHTML += " "` line was causing your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code that you've now clarified your answer with:

```
div.innerHTML += " ";
```

wipes out all previous programmatic event handlers assigned to children of `myId` so the only one that would be left is the last one you add - thus why thus why only the last input handler works.  Assigning to innerHTML reparses the HTML from scratch and re-initializes all those objects.  Any programmatic changes you have made to them (in your case, assign a click handler) may be lost.

The downside of using innerHTML to modify your page is that is may wreck programmatically assigned event handlers and other programmatic changes.  I try to only use it when building new HTML or when setting the contents of one element (e.g. what text displays).

Comment: Thanks for your time and clerification. I am not sure if there is some good web page with javascript documentation (something like php.net for PHP) wich would help me a lot with this kind of problems but I wasn't able to find one.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a scoping issue.

You are accessing a private variable inside an anonymous function.

Try using a closure for your event.

http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=javascript+closures&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8

Comment: Thanks for reply but variable wasnt my problem, I could even alert some static text: alert("asd"); and only last <span> has onclick event registered to it. But I found the problem. See my answer on jfriend00 comment.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried giving different ids for the new  you created?